# Slot Machine using methods

Tags: java

I am making this slot machine for my programming class but I do not know how to get the program to ask if they want to play again and thus run again without causing an infinite loop. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean playAgain = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Welcome, you have 10 credits! Play (Y/N)");
    String choice;
    choice = input.nextLine();
    int credits = 10;
    if ("y".equals(choice))
    {
        playAgain = true;
    } else {
        playAgain = false;
    }
    while (playAgain = true)
    {
        int sp0 = spin();
        int sp1 = spin();
        int sp2 = spin();
        System.out.println(sp0 +"\t"+ sp1 +"\t"+ sp2);
        int answer = evaluate(sp0,sp1,sp2);
        int newCred = answer + credits - 1;
        System.out.println("Your now have "+ newCred + " credits");
        System.out.println("Press y to play again");
        String newC = input.nextLine();


    }


// TODO code application logic here
}
public static int spin()
{
  int num1;
  Random rand = new Random();
  num1 = rand.nextInt(8);
  return num1;


}
public static int evaluate(int e1, int e2, int e3)
{
    int num;
    if(e1==0 && e2==0 && e3==0)
    {

      num= 7;
      System.out.println("You Win");

    }else if (e1==e2 && e2 == e3){
      num = 5;
      System.out.println("You Win");

    }else if ( e1== 0 && e2==0 && e3 != 0 ){
      num= 3; 
      System.out.println("You win");

    } else if (e1==e2 && e2==e1 && e3 != e1){
      num= 2;
      System.out.println("You win");

    } else if (e1==0 && e2 !=0 && e3 != 0){
       num= 1;

       System.out.println("You win");
    } else {
        num =0;
       System.out.println("You Lose");
    }

    return num;
}
```

Comment: May be you need to make sure that the variable `playAgain` changes _inside_ the loop too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line probably doesn't do what you expected:

> ```
> while (playAgain = true)
> ```

The `=` operator is for assignment, `==` is for comparison.
So this line sets the value of `playAgain` to `true`,
and the value of the expression is `true` as well,
so this is an infinite loop.

What you meant to write was is:

```
while (playAgain == true)
```

But you didn't need the `==` operator at all, because you can use boolean expressions directly, like this:

```
while (playAgain)
```

But this is not enough.
Inside the body of the `while` loop, you have nothing to change the value of `playAgain`.
One way to fix that:

```
while (playAgain) {
    int sp0 = spin();
    int sp1 = spin();
    int sp2 = spin();
    System.out.println(sp0 +"\t"+ sp1 +"\t"+ sp2);
    int answer = evaluate(sp0,sp1,sp2);
    int newCred = answer + credits - 1;
    System.out.println("Your now have "+ newCred + " credits");
    System.out.println("Press y to play again");
    playAgain = "y".equals(input.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: `playAgain` would also need to be re-assigned within the loop, based on `newC`.

Comment: Thanks @MickMnemonic, I noticed it too, fixed it now

Comment: Thank you so much you guys are life savers

Answer (score 0):

```
playAgain = true
```

Assign true to playAgain

```
playAgain == true
```

Test playAgain equals true